# Cocoa NSVIew notification when the view gets the key focus?

Tags: cocoa, nsview

How can i get a notification if a NSView gets the key focus?

I expected a method like "windowDidBecomeKey" from NSWindow but either i'm blind or there is nothing like this is NSView.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The key view, when there is one, is the first responder. So, implement [the `becomeFirstResponder` method](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSResponder_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSResponder/becomeFirstResponder) in your view, and either handle that there or post a notification for your controller to listen for.